# not equal release apk in ionic and flutter

Tags: android, flutter, ionic-framework

I had an app in Ionic, after some time I rewrote it with Flutter. Now, when I get the apk output in Flutter, if the old version is installed, it cannot be installed, while the jks file is the same.
Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Flutter based APK, you'll need to uninstall Ionic based App first. The problem of "App not Installed" occurs because your Ionic based App and Flutter based share the same ID. If you need to install Flutter app alongside Ionic app, try changing App ID for Flutter Project.

For example, if your Ionic app had app ID as com.ionic.app
Try renaming Flutter App ID as something else
Like com.flutter.app

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time, I realized that the problem is versionCode and versionName.
versionCode and versionName can be specified in pubspec.yaml version section.

```
version: 1.0.0+1
```

Here, "1.0.0" is the version name and 1 after "+" is the version code.